# Rambler under Google search engine

Tags: google-search, search-engines

These days somehow it started that whenever I search something with Google or any of my search engines in Opera only, I get search result in Rambler (in Russian language). In Preferences I don't have Rambler under the list of search engines. I don't know how it came to Opera, and I don't know how to disable, delete or exclude Rambler?

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the problem?